# How to return 0 with where condition user when user search only space character?

Tags: sql, oracle

Hello I'm using Oracle 11g and i have a data that looks like this

```
no|name|flag
------------
1|kumar|1
2|rajesh singh|1
3|adi sneedar|1
4|danielle castro|1
5|cef danish|1
```

if i did

```
select count(*) from tablename where name like '% %'
```

it will return 2 records.

if i did "multiple spaces", like 2 or more spaces

```
select count(*) from tablename where name like '%    %'
```

it returns 0(this means good)

it will return 5 records.
What i want is if the user only input '% %' it will also return 0. But i also wanted that

```
select count(*) from tablename where name like '%adi sneedar%'
```

it will return 1

How should i do that in the where condition?

Comment: the query should return 4 through use of `WHERE name LIKE '% %' ` if the space-seen characters are really spaces. e.g. they might be non-printable characters. What do you observe when you issue `SELECT t.*, DUMP(name) FROM tablename t`? Do you see any other ASCII values than the counterparts of the letters(with the range 65-90 and 97-122) or space(which's is 32)?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might suffice, assuming that the '%' are being passed as part of the binding input

```
select *
from   mytable
where  name like :bindvar
and    replace(replace(:bindvar,'%'),' ') is not null
```

which basically says they need to enter something that is not solely spaces and percentage signs.